# Cards grid with a specific layout

Tags: css, flexbox, grid

I faced with a problem with the vertical cards position in accordance with the design (image attached). Firstly I tried position it with the `flexbox` property but seems it's not the right way because it is just move element to the next line in a "natural flow" but I don't need such behaviour. The most closest solution was to set `column-count: 2` property to the `news__items` class in parent container but I can't control the order in this case. I feel like `display: grid` can help here but can't figure out how to implement it yet. Note: images have the same height and width.

Here is the html and css markup:

```css
.news__items {
  column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="news__items">
  <div class="news__item">
    <img src="../img/dummy-news-image.png" alt="news">
    <div class="news__item-content">
      <h2 class="news__primary-title">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean sed purus dolor. Phasellus velit libero, dapibus sed felis non, laoreet ornare risus. Morbi imperdiet maximus justo, nec porttitor ligula bibendum non. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed feugiat
        nulla quis mollis egestas. Duis blandit volutpat justo id imperdiet. Maecenas dapibus in quam vitae egestas.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="news__item">
    <img src="../img/dummy-news-image.png" alt="news">
    <div class="news__item-content">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
      <h2 class="news__secondary-title">Lorem ipsum dolor
      </h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean sed purus dolor. Phasellus velit libero, dapibus sed felis non, laoreet ornare risus. Morbi imperdiet maximus justo, nec porttitor ligula bibendum non. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed feugiat
        nulla quis mollis egestas. Duis blandit volutpat justo id imperdiet. Maecenas dapibus in quam vitae egestas.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="news__item">
    <img src="../img/dummy-news-image.png" alt="news">
    <div class="news__item-content">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
      <h2 class="news__secondary-title">Lorem ipsum dolor</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean sed purus dolor. Phasellus velit libero, dapibus sed felis non, laoreet ornare risus. Morbi imperdiet maximus justo, nec porttitor ligula bibendum non. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed feugiat
        nulla quis mollis egestas. Duis blandit volutpat justo id imperdiet. Maecenas dapibus in quam vitae egestas.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="news__item">
    <img src="../img/dummy-news-image.png" alt="news">
    <div class="news__item-content">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
      <h2 class="news__secondary-title">MFF in the News</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean sed purus dolor. Phasellus velit libero, dapibus sed felis non, laoreet ornare risus. Morbi imperdiet maximus justo, nec porttitor ligula bibendum non. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed feugiat
        nulla quis mollis egestas. Duis blandit volutpat justo id imperdiet. Maecenas dapibus in quam vitae egestas.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="news__item">
    <img src="../img/dummy-news-image.png" alt="news">
    <div class="news__item-content">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
      <h2 class="news__secondary-title">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean sed purus dolor. Phasellus velit libero, dapibus sed felis non, laoreet ornare risus. Morbi imperdiet maximus justo, nec porttitor ligula bibendum non. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed feugiat
        nulla quis mollis egestas. Duis blandit volutpat justo id imperdiet. Maecenas dapibus in quam vitae egestas.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

What is the best approach to implement such grids?

Comment: column-count is the easiest, it will balance the content within the number you set. grid, will require to get a few elements spanning a few rows and some other none to avoid the gaps.  Flex/ direction:column requires an explicit height to get the content wrap to another column. Flex and grid will require to know elements height to dispatch them within 2 dense columns, column-count does it itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution.

```
.news__items {
  display: table;
}
.news__item {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```